# Preferred way of swapping big trees (e.g. pages in SPAs): `display: none`, `replaceChild()`, etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, dom

When developing complex web applications, like SPAs, we are faced with the problem of displaying/enabling/keeping updated different parts of the application at different times.

For instance, as a simple example, consider swapping the current page/section/activity of the application in a SPA.

Assuming that these trees are non-trivial (they are entire pages, they may contain CSS animations, event handlers, some non-static content, etc.) and that we care about performance, **what is, nowadays, the preferred way of swapping them in and out? What approach modern frameworks choose? Why?**

In particular, several metrics are important to consider:

- Overall performance/memory usage/etc. (i.e. when not swapping pages)
- Actual time required to switch pages

Note that in order to be as quick as possible, we want to keep the content/pages pre-loaded somehow (i.e. no network requests are discussed here).

---

For context, here are several ways people have used over the years:

- Have some string templates in JS. When pages are switched, replace entirely the contents with `innerHTML` at once (for performance), reattaching handlers and start updating the non-static values as needed at that moment, etc.
- Keeping everything in the DOM (i.e. all elements of all possible pages), but have inactive pages with `display: none`. Then, swap the current page simply switching `display` property in the page going out and the one going in. Also, do not update non-visible pages to avoid performance penalties.
- Keeping the trees in JS (i.e. keep a reference to each top-most `Node` of each page in JS), and swap them in and out of the DOM with e.g. `replaceChild()`.

Comment: what's the underlying reason you are asking this question?  Because the short answer is: use an SPA library/framework and rely upon said library's abstraction to do this work for you in an acceptable way.

Comment: @Brandon The point of the question is to discuss the best approach to perform this with the latest standards and assuming recent browsers, not about using a particular library/framework that abstracts you from it. Giving examples of how/why a particular library/framework does it is useful, of course.

Comment: then your question is too broad.  Post a specific example and then an answer can more readily be provided for that _specific_ use case.

Comment: No, it isn't. The question asks for the best approach, performance-wise, to accomplish a particular task (swapping in and out big DOM trees). To make it even more particular, it puts forth a *specific* example (swapping entire pages in SPAs). It even suggests a few that have been used for context (so an answer may choose to compare/discuss them or even offer a better way). Just because there is no code in the question does not mean it is too broad.

Comment: "best performance-wise" is subjective and depends upon your exact definition of "best" and also depends upon the specific requirements (specific DOM trees with specific "CSS animations, event handlers, some non-static content, etc.".  You are asking for a general one-size-fits-all answer.  That's too broad.

Comment: Performance is not subjective at all, it can be measured and tested, even if there may be several ways to do so -- that is like saying scientific studies are subjective.

Comment: As for the requirements you mention (*"... CSS animations, event handlers, some non-static content, etc."*), they are precisely making the question more concrete, not otherwise (e.g. we are not talking about a single static element). Now, if we were to discuss a specific code sample, with specific elements, then the question would be essentially useless for other readers. That is not the point. Instead, the idea is to provide current best practices for swapping in and out big trees into the main document.